# Block Specific User Agents Globally

Tags: apache, nginx, cpanel, whm

I used to manage all of my web servers manually via **nginx**.

I am now using **cPanel** and would like to block specific user agents from accessing any websites on my server.

This is how easy it was in nginx.

```
 if ($http_user_agent ~* "PHP|curl|Wget|HTTrack|Nmap|Verifying|PingBack|Pingdom|Joomla|Wordpress") { return 444; }
 if ($http_user_agent = "") { return 444; }
 if ($http_user_agent = " ") { return 444; }
 if ($http_user_agent = "-") { return 444; }
```

How do I replicate the same effect for all of my websites including the main web server for **WHM (apache)**.

Seems like a simple request, but there is almost no documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you use map to set a $drop_agent variable at the http level, it'll be available to all your servers. The user agent matches could also put in an included file.

```
map $http_user_agent $drop_agent {
    default 0;
    ~^libwww-perl$  1;
}
```

Then in each server stanza:

```
if ($drop_agent) {
#   return 403; # for testing 
    return 444;
}
```

Comment: I use WHM/cPanel, is this still possible?

Comment: If you have root shell access to the server then it should be possible if you were still running nginx. But I see you are now running apache.

Comment: but yeah I have root access (or used to until I gave my root password to WHMCS the scam to help fix my server)

Comment: If you could configure apache to listen on a different port, I suppose you could install nginx then proxy pass to apache.

Comment: Too much for such a simple configuration request. This is where Apache SEVERELY lacks..

Comment: Ok I am able to set a global .htaccess, doesn't seem to block the attacks but it I will post it in the edit. How can I return a no response?